# DOJO XHRPOST DATAGRID

Tags: gridview, dojo

I am trying to load the following xml data rendered from a JSP page and display the name, city , state and hide zip. How do I do it in dojo?
I have tried some code , but have not made any big progress. The code works for JSON data.

### XML DATA rendered from a JSP/Servlet

customers/
 /customer
  /name/JOHN DOE/name/
  /city/SFO/city/
  /state/CA/state/
  /zip/94087/zip/
 /customer
 /customer
  /name/SUSAN SMITH/name/
  /city/CHICAGO/city/
  /state/IL/state/
  /zip/61706/zip/
 /customer/
/customers/

---

JAVASCRIPT CODE

---

// make request to the customers web service 
function loadTable(page){

```
var targetURL = "test.jsp"; 
dojo.xhrGet({
    url: targetURL,
    handleAs: "xml",
    mimetype: "text/xml",
    load: handleResponse,
    error: handleError
});
```

}

var view1 = {
    cells: [
        [
            {name: 'Company', field: "name"},
            {name: 'City', field: "city"},
            {name: 'State',field: "state"},
            {name: 'Zip',field: "zip"}
        ]
    ]
};
// a grid layout is an array of views.
var layout = [ view1 ];
// the model will contain the data to be displayed in the view 
model = new dojox.grid.data.Objects([{key: "name"}, {key: "city"},{key: "state"},{key: "zip"}], null);

// Process the response from the customers web service 
function handleResponse(data, ioArgs){
  dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
  dojo.require("dojox.xml.DomParser");
**HOW do I load data into the model here?**
     //alert(data);
 var jsonStore = dojox.xml.DomParser.parse(data);

```
// set the model object with the returned customers list to be displayed in grid 
model.setData(jsonStore);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put and items argument with the list of all your data see [here](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore#item-structure)